# Is this inefficient?

Tags: c++, enums, int

[Extending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963031/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-enum-as-int) this question, I wanted to use my enumed val as they're "supposed" to be,

```
#include <stdio.h>
enum E{ A, B, C } ;

#define inc(enVal) (*((int*)&enVal))++

int main()
{
  E t = A ;
  inc( t ) ;
  printf( "t %d\n", t ) ;
}
```

Now uh, `t` is a variable of enum'd type E, and I have a macro `inc` that increases the value of `t` by 1,

So is this macro (and presumably other macros like it for flag checking) going to be that much less efficient than just using `int t` instead?

Comment: Not so much "inefficient" as "wrong".

Comment: why not use an int if you want to increment it? also, see the disassembly and see what actually goes on :)

Comment: Is this even defined behaviour?

Comment: @Andrei: You mean, "what just so happens to go on in _this_ build"

Comment: @Tomalak: do you imagine this to be useful enough to actually be built on multiple compilers? this is the only build that matters and therefore the only one that needs examining :)

Comment: @Andrei: He could well be using it as a part of a larger build which *does* have multiple compile targets.

Comment: @Andrei: The question is tagged "C++", not "my one-time build on this specific computer"

Comment: @Tomalak: but the answer differs depending on the compiler used (is the enum backed by an int or not); so unless it's open source or similar, all you "really" care is what happens on your compiler ...and whether the maintenance programmer knows where you live

Comment: @Andrei: Whether the underlying type is `int` doesn't depend just on the compiler but on the code. All the semantics that you need to care about are pretty clearly stated in the standard.

Comment: @Andrei: "but the answer differs depending on the compiler used" Yea. It is exactly the reason why it is wrong.

Answer (score 11):

No, it's not going to be less efficient. It will, however, be incredibly, hideously, wrong. Please, don't ever.

Oh, especially since the backing type of enums is undefined and they might well actually be compiled to less than the size of an `int` on some compilers.

Answer (score 5):

Come on, it's ok to overload for enums:

```
E& operator ++ (E& x)
{
    x = E((int)x + 1);
    return x;
}
```

See [in action](http://ideone.com/fQcIh).

Comment: That's not what he was doing.

Comment: @Neil: why not? except his version returning an int type before the increment and mine returns the correct type after the increment?

Comment: @nbt This is what he *should* have been doing, *instead* of the bogus macro.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this violates the strict-aliasing rules in the standard, and not only that it won't work right for `C` at all. What are you really trying to do? Does it actually make SENSE to increment the value?

Say you're trying to implement a state machine, much better is to just have a `vector`/array lookup table and use that to move to a new state.

Are you sure you shouldn't just be using an `int` instead, if you want to be able to assume that the enumerated values are consecutive?